# How to animate coloring a line like a signal passing through in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx, line, stroke

In JavaFX, I'm trying to achieve a smooth animation of a line (more exactly a Polyline),where it looks like a signal is traveling through that line. Line is 
colored with some color (say, black) and continuously recolors with a new color (say, red). So at the beginning the line is black and at the end, line is red.

How can I achieve this ? Example in pictures below.

[Beginning of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4illE.png)

[During animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m28W9.png)

[End of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDrCZ.png)

Please, note that direction matters.

I tried combining StrokeTransition and PathTransition, but have no clue how to do that correctly:

```
  PathTransition pt = new PathTransition(Duration.seconds(5), MWFsignal);
  StrokeTransition st = new StrokeTransition(Duration.ZERO);

  SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition(pt, st);
  seq.play();
```

My logic was this: first travel through the polyline and as you travel,
apply stroke transition on that part you've traveled so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DoubleProperty` representing the position of the "signal", as a value from 0 to 1.

Then bind the `stroke` of the line to that property, generating a `LinearGradient` that changes from red to black at the value of the position. You can then just animate the signal position using any standard animation:

```
    DoubleProperty signalPosition = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    line.strokeProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
        new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, 
                new Stop(0, Color.CORAL),
                new Stop(signalPosition.get(), Color.CORAL),
                new Stop(signalPosition.get(), Color.BLACK),
                new Stop(1, Color.BLACK)), 
        signalPosition));

    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,       new KeyValue(signalPosition, 0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(signalPosition, 1))
    );
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedPolylineStroke extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane root = new Pane();
        Polyline line = new Polyline(new double[] {
            100.0, 300.0,
            300.0, 100.0,
            500.0, 300.0
        });
        line.setStrokeWidth(4);
        root.getChildren().add(line);

        DoubleProperty signalPosition = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        line.strokeProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
            new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, 
                    new Stop(0, Color.CORAL),
                    new Stop(signalPosition.get(), Color.CORAL),
                    new Stop(signalPosition.get(), Color.BLACK),
                    new Stop(1, Color.BLACK)), 
            signalPosition));

        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,       new KeyValue(signalPosition, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(signalPosition, 1))
        );

        root.setOnMouseClicked(e -> animation.playFromStart());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        animation.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```